# algorithm for (regex)/String pattern recognition

Tags: java, machine-learning, pattern-matching, nlp

I have a file which includes some strings like..

```
P31XYFT5
3YTTXPL
```

this is a sample, the file could contains +100K of these strings , 
I need to find these strings and extract them , what algorithm (including machine learning algorithms) i can use

Comment: And do _you_ know what to look for? Apart from there being common characters in both of these?

Comment: am looking for these patterns , mix of alphanumeric characters with no specified order

Comment: hi! regex seems to be the right approach for a simple task like this but you need to know (1) which characters to expect (and you already told us, although it would help to know if you expect all caps, for instance), (2) which characters not to expect, so we can include those, (3) the context in which they appear so we can exclude it, (4) length of the strings you're looking for. ideally, post a snippet of the data. more ideally, however, try debuggex.com or regex101.com to help out in building your regex

Comment: How did you solve this? I also have a similar problem.

Comment: machine learning classification

Comment: Which algorithm? Please elaborate

Answer (score 1):

I will try to give you suggestions but @fge is right, you need to know what to look for.

If your file contains valid words you could use dictionaries to recognize the existing and non-existing words.

If you could know the pattern for the words that should be excluded - you could apply it to detect that words.

Speaking about machine learning algorithms - I have more experience with images so can cannot help you much. For images you just have to extract the features and predict/learn, for example, the Support Vector Machine (SVM). Something similar might be used here.